# how to create commerce product attributes which gets it's values from a view

Tags: views, commerce

I want to fill the product attributes select list with data like:

location1
location2
location3

These locations are general and gathered using a custom module. In views I can create a list with these values, but I'm unable to use them as attributes.

Comment: Why not generate the list of attributes from the custom module directly?

Comment: True! Any help or directions in how to do this? couldn't find anything in the Code recipes on drupalcommers.org - thanks for your help!